# I want to create an AuthGuard so that after successful login, it prevents access to the login page

Tags: angular, typescript, user-interface

login.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs';
import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { LoginService } from 'src/app/services/login.service';

interface User {
  username: string;
  userroll: string; // Adjust the property name if needed
  userpassword: string;
}
@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: './login.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
export class LoginComponent {


  constructor(private user: LoginService, private route: Router, private http: HttpClient) { }

  isUserLoggedIn: boolean = false;

 
  login(data: any) {
    this.user.getUsers().subscribe(
       (response: any) => {
        console.log('Users response:', response);

        if (response && Array.isArray(response.users)) {
          const users: User[] = response.users;

          const user = users.find((u: User) => u.username === data.userName && u.userpassword === data.userpassword);
          console.log('Username:', data.username);
          console.log('Password:', data.userpassword);
          if (user) {
            this.route.navigate(['dashboard']);
          } else {
            console.error('Invalid username or password');
          }
        } else {
          console.error('Invalid data format: Users data is not an array');
        }
      },
      (error) => {
        console.error('Error fetching users:', error);
      }
    );
    this.isUserLoggedIn = true;
  }








}
```

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from "@angular/common/http";
import { Observable, catchError, of, tap } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoginService {
  

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }
  
  private usersUrl = '/assets/xyz.json';
  // private isAuthenticated = false;
  getUsers(): Observable<any[]> {
    return this.http.get<any[]>(this.usersUrl);
  }

  userLogin(data: any): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users', data);
  }

 

  
  // userLogin(data: any): Observable<any> {
  //   // Assuming your backend API returns a token upon successful login
  //   return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/users', data).pipe(
  //     tap((loginResponse: any) => {
  //       if (loginResponse && loginResponse.token) {
  //         // Set authentication status to true upon successful login
  //         this.isAuthenticated = true;
  //       } else {
  //         // Set authentication status to false if login is unsuccessful
  //         this.isAuthenticated = false;
  //       }
  //     }),
  //     catchError(error => {
  //       console.error('Login failed:', error);
  //       // Return an observable with the error
  //       return of(error);
  //     })
  //   );
  // }

  // userLogout(): void {
  //   // Assuming your logout API clears the user session
  //   // Add your logout logic here
  //   this.isAuthenticated = false;
  // }

  // isAuthenticatedUser(): boolean {
  //   return this.isAuthenticated;
  // }
  
}
```

This is the login.service file. I want that when I successfully login, it navigates to the dashboard page, and I want that it logins only the data that is present in the json file. After login, it does not update the data in the json file.

Also, I want that after success, it does not give access to the navigate to login page.

Comment: "I want that it logins only the data that is present in the json file. After login, it does not update the data in the json file."  I'm not sure how anyone could help you with this if you don't describe what that file even is.  I'm also not sure what you mean by "update the data in the json file" given you've described nothing about how that happens.